Should we keep the question about GLBSE protected?
The recent question about the GLBSE closing down was protected by me. However, some believe the protection was unwarranted. Should we keep this question protected?

I think protection is warranted to prevent significant abuse/misuse. While I don't know which number counts as "significant", I think we're just not there yet.
Just downvote + comment any inappropriate answer.

I would tend to agree that we're not at an abusive point just yet, but rest assured the mods will be keeping a close eye on this question. The moment we're spending too much time moderating one question it will get protected :)

I believe this question should be protected. For not we have 3 answers with reputation 1 - one is just a random comment, one is making claims without giving sources, and one being balanced, but a bit uninformative. I'd rather avoid the mess of the first two types of answers by keeping the question protected.
